# How to accept only an empty object?

Tags: typescript

```
const x: {} = {a:1}
```

The above code compiles. How can I accept only an empty object: `{}`?

---

- I know that `{}` accepts any object containing multiple `key`. I'm looking for a way to declare a type that accept only an object without any keys.

Comment: I am curious, what is your use case?

Comment: I have a `serialize` function from object to string and `deserialize` that does the opposite. the `deserialize` may fail so I return an empty object. so the `deserialize` function's return type is `{ aaa : number ; bbb : string ; ... } | empty-object`

Comment: Why not return undefined or null?

Comment: i guess I will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can user `never` to force an object to be empty:

```
type Empty = { [key: string]: never }
```

See a Typescript Playground: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAogtmUUC8UDeUDaBrCIBcUAzsAE4CWAdgOYC6hlEAbhKVAL4DcAUNwMYB7SiSgAPQvEQgU6LvyEiCsBElQZxUAIwdOQA

Answer (score 1):

And I would argue that this is impossible because even in strongly typed languages, you cannot restrict from accepting a more derived type.

And what you have here is basically (under the hood) saying that `x` should be at least of type `{}`.

Therefore I see a few options here:

- return `null` or `undefined`
- throw an exception if it fails (which is very standard in such scenarios)
- Have some `Option` type that either has a value or doesn't, which is a more functional way of solving the problem of either returning a value or a failure. [This has more info on the topic.](https://tech.evojam.com/2016/03/21/practical-intro-to-monads-in-javascript-either/)

EDIT: Phillip provided how to achieve it, so my guess was wrong. But I still wouldn't recommend using it if possible.

Comment: thanks for the great info. i think you are right. optional is not an option in the project im working on (sadly) and i pretty much hate to return null/undefined. i think that i will return undefined. (+ i must accept Phillip answer but i will probably go with you)